# ASP.NET making a user controlled template with WebControls in them

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I would like to make a system where my users can customize the look and feel of my webapp.

My goal is to give them an HTML editor and some predefined tags like [BUYBUTTON] and [PRODUCTLIST] they can use.

These tags should be replaced with actual ASCX controls so that they not only display the HTML output, but have any code-behind functionality.

A generic find and replace of text/html is easy, I can't wrap my head around how to make the controls embed into the template.

Can someone give me a little push in the right direction here? I will be doing this within a DNN module if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at how DNN's XML Skin parser works.
I wasn't able to find any good tutorials but here is a [link](http://dotnetnukeconsulting.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/new-token-format-for-dnn-5/) so you at least know what Im talking about.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look at the source code of announcement module, which is doing almost same thing that you want to do.

Only difference here is, announcement module is storing the template in settings, so you can have different layout templates for different modules on same page/portal.

Hope this will help you, happy coding